# vue-material and vee-validate work together

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, material-design, vue-material, vee-validate

I tried to make vue-material and vee-validate work together but had some issue. Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sw81v4aq/1/)

The basic example without material is working but the material design one is not.

```
  <md-field v-validate="'required|email'" name="email1">
    <label>Email</label>
    <md-input v-model="initial" type="text"></md-input>
     <span>{{ errors.first('email1') }}</span>
  </md-field>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use v-validate on md-input. And add data-vv-name

```
 <md-input v-model="initial" type="text" v-validate="'required|email'" data-vv-name="email1"></md-input>
```

Comment: I tried but still not working. Please see my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yevx9mp7/1/